# Android Fatal signal 11 SIGSEGV

Tags: android, android-ndk

While developing, an error has been appearing randomly. I've ignored it (my fault) because the application needed to be released, I haven't found a solution anywhere and it is driving me crazy.

Anyways,

Logcat prints this error:

> A/libc: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8f6eed8 passed to dlfree
>
> A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 5429 (FinalizerDaemon)

As this is telling me nothing I can understand, searching how to debug a SIGSEGV error, I opened the ndk-stak.

> adb logcat | ndk-stack -sym

And the log prints this error:

```
5421  5429 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 5429 (FinalizerDaemon)
3369  3369 D powerUI : accValue============42
3369  3369 D powerUI : mCputempVlaue============42
989  3846 E IzatSvc_PassiveLocListener: E/Exiting with error virtual void izat_manager::IzatPassiveLocationListener::onLocationChanged(const izat_manager::IzatLocation*, izat_manager::IzatLocationStatus) line 113 "1"
304   304 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
304   304 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'bq/Aquaris_M5/Aquaris_M5:6.0.1/MMB29M/1496676247:user/release-keys'
304   304 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
304   304 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
304   304 F DEBUG   : pid: 5421, tid: 5429, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> com.vigilant.pycseca <<<
A/libc: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8f6eed8 passed to dlfree
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 5429 (FinalizerDaemon)
```

This is telling me nothing I can understand, searching how to debug a SIGSEGV error, I opened the ndk-stak.

```
 adb logcat |  ndk-stack -sym
```

The log prints this error:

```
434   434 I MSM-irqbalance: Decided to move IRQ131 from CPU7 to CPU4
5421  5429 F libc    : invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8f6eed8 passed to dlfree
5421  5429 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 5429 (FinalizerDaemon)
3369  3369 D powerUI : accValue============42
3369  3369 D powerUI : mCputempVlaue============42
989  3846 E IzatSvc_PassiveLocListener: E/Exiting with error virtual void izat_manager::IzatPassiveLocationListener::onLocationChanged(const izat_manager::IzatLocation*, izat_manager::IzatLocationStatus) line 113 "1"
304   304 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
304   304 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'bq/Aquaris_M5/Aquaris_M5:6.0.1/MMB29M/1496676247:user/release-keys'
304   304 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
304   304 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
304   304 F DEBUG   : pid: 5421, tid: 5429, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> com.vigilant.pycseca <<<
304   304 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xdeadbaad
304   304 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8f6eed8 passed to dlfree'
304   304 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 00000002
304   304 F DEBUG   :     r4 b8f6eed8  r5 deadbaad  r6 b6d87eb8  r7 a2eae000
304   304 F DEBUG   :     r8 b8f6eee0  r9 b8fa3ac8  sl 2324aee0  fp 23258680
304   304 F DEBUG   :     ip b6d825dc  sp b4162538  lr b6d54887  pc b6d54886  cpsr 60070030
304   304 F DEBUG   :
304   304 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
304   304 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00030886  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1285)
304   304 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 72b882d5  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x1f41000)
989  6018 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.vigilant.pycseca/.activities.Login
304   304 F DEBUG   :
304   304 F DEBUG   : Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_00
304   304 E DEBUG   : AM write failed: Broken pipe> 304   304 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xdeadbaad
304   304 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8f6eed8 passed to dlfree'
304   304 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 00000002
304   304 F DEBUG   :     r4 b8f6eed8  r5 deadbaad  r6 b6d87eb8  r7 a2eae000
304   304 F DEBUG   :     r8 b8f6eee0  r9 b8fa3ac8  sl 2324aee0  fp 23258680
304   304 F DEBUG   :     ip b6d825dc  sp b4162538  lr b6d54887  pc b6d54886  cpsr 60070030
304   304 F DEBUG   :
304   304 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
304   304 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00030886  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1285)
304   304 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 72b882d5  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x1f41000)
989  6018 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.vigilant.pycseca/.activities.Login
304   304 F DEBUG   :
304   304 F DEBUG   : Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_00
304   304 E DEBUG   : AM write failed: Broken pipe
```

While it says something about onLocationChanged, disabling gps doesn't solution the error.

Do you have any idea what can be happening?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> A/libc: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8f6eed8 passed to dlfree

Probably a double free. Maybe a bogus pointer passed to free.